# How can I define a template class by constraining the set of allowed types, and reference a Collection of these in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I am defining the following class:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    T _value;

    public T getValue() { 
        return T;

    public void setValue(T value) {
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

T should only be of type int, char, or double.

I want to be able to reference a collection of these, such as:

```
interface IBar {
    Collection<Foo> getAllFoo();
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work since I'd need to specify the type T with this reference. So, I need to define some abstract base class that I can use instead.

The question is, how can I enforce that all derived types implement the getValue() and setValue() functions? I know I can define them in the abstract base as abstract methods returning / accepting an Object, but that doesn't provide type safety on the 3 accepted primitives.

Is there a better way to define a collection of these, and is there a way to enforce T being either int, char, or double?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to constrain the type `T` to be assignable to `java.lang.Number`? That's more broad than `int`, `char`, and `double`, but I wonder if that constraint is more in spirit than letter.

Comment: @seh: `Character` doesn't extend `Number`.

Comment: Yes, I know. Hence my *spirit v. letter* question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're better off creating concrete implementations for each type you care about.

```
interface Foo<T>{
    public T getValue();
    public void setValue(T value);
}

class IntFoo implements Foo<Integer>{...}
class CharFoo implements Foo<Character>{...}
class DoubleFoo implements Foo<Double>{...}

interface Bar{
    Collection<Foo<?>> getAllFoo();
}
```

The `?` allows the collection to contain any type of `Foo` object. You still lose the generic type when you reference a `Foo<?>`, but there's no good way around that.

Other than having the common base class, there really is no advantage of doing this. If you had some common ground each `Foo` could resolve to, then I would do this:

```
abstract class Foo<T>{
    T value;

    T getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    void setValue(T value){
        this.value=value;
    }

    // return whatever is appropriate for all implementations
    abstract Object baz(); 
}

class IntFoo implements Foo<Integer>{
    Object baz(){
        return null // something useful;
    }
}

Collection<Foo<?>> foos = bar.getAllFoo();
for(Foo<?> foo:foos){
    foo.baz();
}
```

Comment: Nice. This is what I started with, but I forgot how to use the Foo<?> syntax. Many thanks!

Comment: No problem! I am not sure what you are trying to do, but I provided an alternate way of abstracting the generic types for when using a collection of `Foo` objects.

Comment: Yep, I'm going with the abstract class for other reasons. Glad to see you're validating my approach!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Foo<T> 
    private Foo(){} // only nested classes can access

    static public class Int extends Foo<Integer>{}
    static public class Char extends Foo<Character>{}
    static public class Double extends Foo<Double>{}

public class MyIntFoo extends Foo.Int // MyIntFoo is a Foo<Integer>
```

There is no way to create a subclass of `Foo` whose `T` is not one of `Integer/Character/Double`. If the 3 nested classes are `final`, then they are the only subclasses of `Foo`.

We still can't prevent a `Foo<Float>` type declaration. But at least you know such an object cannot be instantiated.